# linkedin share button wordpress grab url of current page

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi there I have been trying to make my own share button for LinkedIn, for my wordpress site since my theme doesn't support it and I can't seem to get the developer option in the LinkedIn help to work for me.

I have created this from what I have found on the net and my very limited knowledge of PHP and code. I have gotta to the point where I can create a window that lets you sign in to LinkedIn to post content, I just can't grab the URL from the address bar, so it will share that specific blog post.

I have been putting this code at the bottom of single.php in my WP child theme.

All I need to do is figure out how to grab the url from the address bar and insert it into the posting box.

Thank you. Here is my code.

```
<?php
$Url = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
$Url .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
?>

<div class="linkedInButton"><a class="linkedIn" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open( 'http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=<?php echo $Url; ?>', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0, status=0, width=626, height=436');return false;" title="Linkedin" ><button class="linkedInButton"><span class="character"><img class="linkedInShare" src="uploads/2018/09/linkedin-logo.png">Share on LinkedIn</span></button></a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
<?php 
    global $wp;
?>

<div class="linkedInButton"><a class="linkedIn" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open( 'http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=<?php echo home_url( $wp->request ); ?>', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0, status=0, width=626, height=436');return false;" title="Linkedin" ><button class="linkedInButton"><span class="character"><img class="linkedInShare" src="uploads/2018/09/linkedin-logo.png">Share on LinkedIn</span></button></a></div>
```

Comment: I still get exactly the same as what I have currently. The box and everything for linked in comes up and lets you sign in to post. Although the blog post you are currently viewing is not showing there be posted.

Comment: Are you trying this locally?  If so upload to remote and try it from a page with a real URL, not localhost

Comment: That is it actually. Thank you, didn't realise that.